# Arrange Deeply Nested Json Array windows phone c#

Tags: c#, json, restsharp, arrays

I have the following JSON string :

```
{
    "response": {
        "hash": "5e042385c8e1d674056e53483828759e",
        "resp_code": "USER_SESSION_RETRIEVED",
        "code": 200
    },
    "structure": {
        "company": {
            "company_id": 3,
            "company_name": "The Ministry of Vaccines",
            "alarm_cnt": 4,
            "regions": [
                {
                    "sites": [
                        {
                            "assets": [
                                {
                                    "asset_id": 71,
                                    "asset_name": "Unassigned",
                                    "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                    "active_component_cnt": 1,
                                    "components": [
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "21.6°C",
                                            "component_id": 503,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Ambient",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-09-13 04:00:00"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "asset_id": 72,
                                    "asset_name": "Pharmacy fridge",
                                    "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                    "active_component_cnt": 2,
                                    "components": [
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "6.7°C",
                                            "component_id": 499,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Top",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-09-13 04:00:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "11.5°C",
                                            "component_id": 500,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Bottom",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-09-13 04:00:00"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "site_id": 35,
                            "site_name": "Acadia Pharmacy"
                        }
                    ],
                    "region_name": "Acadia Pharmacy",
                    "region_id": 25
                },
                {
                    "sites": [
                        {
                            "assets": [
                                {
                                    "asset_id": 73,
                                    "asset_name": "Cold room A",
                                    "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                    "active_component_cnt": 6,
                                    "components": [
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "-",
                                            "component_id": 339,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Probe 1",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "-"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "-",
                                            "component_id": 333,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Digital - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Door",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "-"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "-",
                                            "component_id": 334,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Digital - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Mains Power",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "-"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "asset_id": 27,
                                    "asset_name": "Offices",
                                    "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                    "active_component_cnt": 3,
                                    "components": [
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "25.4°C",
                                            "component_id": 178,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Boardroom Temperature",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-08-18 12:50:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "Probe Err. (OC)",
                                            "component_id": 179,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "ICE 3 A1 -  Temperature",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-10-22 14:01:00",
                                            "sensor_error": true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "25.7°C",
                                            "component_id": 182,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "ICE3 - Ian's Office",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-10-22 14:01:00"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "asset_id": 26,
                                    "asset_name": "Peter Lamonts Fridge",
                                    "alarm_cnt": 3,
                                    "active_component_cnt": 5,
                                    "components": [
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "25.4°C",
                                            "component_id": 175,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 1,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Top Probe Temperature",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-08-18 12:50:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "25.4°C",
                                            "component_id": 176,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 1,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Mid Probe Temperature",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-08-18 12:50:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "25.4°C",
                                            "component_id": 177,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 1,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Bottom Probe Temperature",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-08-18 12:50:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "On",
                                            "component_id": 183,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Digital - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Mains Power Peter Lamonts Fridge",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-08-18 12:50:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "Open",
                                            "component_id": 184,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Digital - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Door Peter Lamonts Fridge",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-08-18 12:50:00"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "asset_id": 28,
                                    "asset_name": "Zero Fridge  Freezer",
                                    "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                    "active_component_cnt": 3,
                                    "components": [
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "Probe Err. (OC)",
                                            "component_id": 95,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Zero Freezer",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-08-18 12:20:00",
                                            "sensor_error": true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "Probe Err. (OC)",
                                            "component_id": 96,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Zero Fridge",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-08-18 12:20:00",
                                            "sensor_error": true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "",
                                            "component_id": 103,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Digital - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Mains Power",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-08-18 12:20:00"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "site_id": 14,
                            "site_name": "21 Cradock Avenue"
                        }
                    ],
                    "region_name": "Rosebank",
                    "region_id": 3
                },
                {
                    "sites": [
                        {
                            "assets": [
                                {
                                    "asset_id": 44,
                                    "asset_name": "Dions Kitchen",
                                    "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                    "active_component_cnt": 1,
                                    "components": [
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "19.1°C",
                                            "component_id": 291,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Ambient (Ice3)",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-10-22 21:51:00"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "asset_id": 31,
                                    "asset_name": "Vaccine Fridge",
                                    "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                    "active_component_cnt": 6,
                                    "components": [
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "30.3°C",
                                            "component_id": 87,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "A1:(Fridge) Ambient Temperature (BC540)",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-10-30 14:20:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "28.9°C",
                                            "component_id": 88,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "A2:Fridge Temp (BC540)",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-10-30 14:20:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "29.7°C",
                                            "component_id": 89,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "A3:Fridge (BC540)",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-10-30 14:20:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "6.6°C",
                                            "component_id": 21,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "ICE3 - A1 Fridge section",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-10-22 21:51:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "-14.9°C",
                                            "component_id": 22,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Analogue - Input",
                                            "component_name": "ICE3 - A2 Freezer section",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-10-22 21:51:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "latest_reading": "",
                                            "component_id": 25,
                                            "alarm_cnt": 0,
                                            "component_type": "Digital - Input",
                                            "component_name": "Mains Power",
                                            "latest_reading_tstamp": "2014-10-30 14:20:00"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "site_id": 2,
                            "site_name": "37 Wandel Ave"
                        }
                    ],
                    "region_name": "Sandton",
                    "region_id": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have created these classes using json2csharp:

```
    public class Response
    {
        public string hash { get; set; }
        public string resp_code { get; set; }
        public int code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Component
    {
        public string latest_reading { get; set; }
        public int component_id { get; set; }
        public int alarm_cnt { get; set; }
        public string component_type { get; set; }
        public string component_name { get; set; }
        public string latest_reading_tstamp { get; set; }
        public bool? sensor_error { get; set; }
    }

    public class Asset
    {
        public int asset_id { get; set; }
        public string asset_name { get; set; }
        public int alarm_cnt { get; set; }
        public int active_component_cnt { get; set; }
        public List<Component> components { get; set; }
    }

    public class Site
    {
        public List<Asset> assets { get; set; }
        public int site_id { get; set; }
        public string site_name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Region
    {
        public List<Site> sites { get; set; }
        public string region_name { get; set; }
        public int region_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public int company_id { get; set; }
        public string company_name { get; set; }
        public int alarm_cnt { get; set; }
        public List<Region> regions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Structure
    {
        public Company company { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Response response { get; set; }
        public Structure structure { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is what I've done so far

```
var client = new RestClient() { BaseUrl = url };
var request = new RestRequest()
{ 
    Resource = "", 
    Method = Method.GET, 
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json 
};

request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response, handle) =>
{
    RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = 
        new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer();
    var resp = deserial.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(response);
    var JSONObj = deserial.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);

    string structure = JSONObj["structure"].ToString();
}
```

That gives me all the data under "Structure"

I need to get the RegionNames listed into list boxes; I need to get the List of Sites under each Region; I also need to get the Assets under each Site listed as well, according to the precious selected field.

My problem now is using the data.  I use the RestSharp client.
I have to group the data accordingly: All Regions, Sites, Assets. The Sites must be grouped under the Region they belong to; the Assets must be grouped under the sites they belong to as well.  Does anyone know how I can do this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hi pls follow this link  http://197.96.22.218:8080/Phase3JEE-war/v1.0/614b0c4d3f78f1e0c8cb8661aa657a05/user_session/?sections=app-basic&company_id=3

Comment: I've edited your question to include the reformatted JSON from your link.  I cut some of it out to make it fit within the character limit.  The remaining JSON validates with jsonlint.com and I think still communicates the structure you are using.

Comment: thanx Brian.. now do u hve any idea how i can accomplish what i need to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 2):

JSON means JavaScript **Object** Notation.

To deserialize, you should create a C# **object** that looks like that JSON object (same property names, sane data types).

Then you can deserialize the object with

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyJSONObjectType>(jsonstring);
```

For instance, a JSON string

```
{success:true,data:[{id:1,name:'Sam'},{id:2,name:'Jim'}]}
```

could be deserialized into the object

```
public class MyJSONObjectType {
    public bool success;
    public List<MySubObj> data;
}
public class MySubObj {
    public int id;
    public string name;
}
```

Comment: thanx.. but ive Deserialised the JSON Response..  my problem is arranging the data and groping it in relevant listboxes.. i used RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer

Comment: So, in fact, your question is absolutely unclear, if not misleading. Please post your question in such a way that we can understand your problem. Especially, post your code.

Comment: ive edited my question and included my code, hope im making a litte sense now